# JavaScript Regex: How to split Regex subexpression matches in to multi-dimensional string arrays?

Tags: javascript, regex

**How would you split Regex subexpression matches in to multi-dimensional string arrays?**

I have a "myvar" string of:

`1-4:2;5-9:1.89;10-24:1.79;25-99:1.69;100-149:1.59;150-199:1.49;200-249:1.39;250+:1.29`

which is a repeat of `QuantityLow - QuantityHigh : PriceEach ;`

I used this "myreg" Regex `/(\d+)[-+](\d*):(\d+\.?\d*);?/g`

Used it with `var myarray = myvar.match(myreg);`

that produced:

`myarray[0] = "1-4:2;"`
`myarray[1] = "5-9:1.89;"`
`myarray[2] = "10-24:1.79;"`
`myarray[3] = "25-99:1.69;"`
`myarray[4] = "100-149:1.59;"`
`myarray[5] = "150-199:1.49;"`
`myarray[6] = "200-249:1.39;"`
`myarray[7] = "250+:1.29"`

Fantastic!  Except that I need the strings broken further by the Q1 - Q2 : P as noted above.  The regex is already setup to identify the parts with parenthesis.  I would think this could be done with a single Regex expression, or at least two, rather than setting up some sort of loop.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't say what the exact output you expect, but I imagine something like this output may be intuitive.

Given:

```
var myvar = "1-4:2;5-9:1.89;10-24:1.79;25-99:1.69;100-149:1.59;150-199:1.49;200-249:1.39;250+:1.29";
```

A quick way to capture all sub-matches is:

```
var matches = [];
myvar.replace(/(\d+)[-+](\d*):(\d+\.?\d*);?/g, function(m, a, b, c) {
    matches.push([a, b, c])
});
```

(Note: you can capture the same output with a [potentially more readable] loop):

```
var myreg = /(\d+)[-+](\d*):(\d+\.?\d*);?/g;
var matches = [];
while(myreg.exec(myvar)) {
    matches.push([RegExp.$1, RegExp.$2, RegExp.$3])
}
```

Either way, the outcome is an array of matches:

```
matches[0]; // ["1", "4", "2"]
matches[1]; // ["5", "9", "1.89"]
matches[2]; // ["10", "24", "1.79"]
matches[3]; // ["25", "99", "1.69"]
matches[4]; // ["100", "149", "1.59"]
matches[5]; // ["150", "199", "1.49"]
matches[6]; // ["200", "249", "1.39"]
matches[7]; // ["250", "", "1.29"]
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I didn't know you could put an anonymous function within the regex methods.  Great!

Answer (score 2):

```
var r = /(\d+)[-+](\d*):(\d+\.?\d*);?/g;
var s = "1-4:2;5-9:1.89;10-24:1.79;25-99:1.69;100-149:1.59;150-199:1.49;200-249:1.39;250+:1.29";
var match;
while ((match = r.exec(s)) != null) {
  console.log("From " + match[1] + " to " + match[2] + " is " + match[3]);
}
```

The `console.log()` call is a Firefox/Firebug call. You can of course use `alert()`, `document.write()` or whatever else suits.

See [RegExp object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), in particular the [RegExp methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Methods_2), most notably [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to do it - using split method of String:

```
var myvar = "1-4:2;5-9:1.89;10-24:1.79;25-99:1.69;100-149:1.59;150-199:1.49;200-249:1.39;250+:1.29";
myvar.split(';');
```

that produced:

```
["1-4:2", "5-9:1.89", "10-24:1.79", "25-99:1.69", "100-149:1.59", "150-199:1.49", "200-249:1.39", "250+:1.29"]
```

Comment: As Dr. Zim already mentioned in his original post, getting the *main* tokens from the string was not the problem. Processing the range and price of the individual tokens was the issue.