# JavaScript match-function - Return Array of found elements?

Tags: javascript

i have a string which has the following format (3,1,Mayer,Jack). I need all 4 elements as own variables. I thought about using JavaScript's match()-function to do this, but i don't know how i can get the 4 elements in variables...

I tried it with this code:

```
var clickedId = '(3,1,Mayer,Jack)';
var pregId = clickedId.match(/([\d]+,[\d]+,[\w]+,[\w]+)/g);
alert(pregId[0]);
```

But i get a popup windows with "(3,1,Mayer,Jack)"... I thought about something like this:

```
var id = pregId[0];
var teamid = pregId[1];
var surname = pregId[2];
var name = pregId[3];
```

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just be careful with the "(" you are using. You're creating a group, not matching a parentesis. If your intention were to match the parentesis, you'll need to escape it: "\\(".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match` function is matching the whole expression, not pulling out the parts of the whole.  So you need to match on each individual element, say with a regex like `(\d|\w)+`.  Here's an example:

```
var clickedId = '(3,1,Mayer,Jack)';
var pregId = clickedId.match(/((\d|\w)+)/g);

var id = pregId[0];
var teamid = pregId[1];
var surname = pregId[2];
var name = pregId[3];

alert(surname);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Znu7N/

Comment: Actually, it looks like it may be possible to pull parts of the whole.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570066/javascript-regex-how-to-split-regex-subexpression-matches-in-to-multi-dimension

Answer (score 0):

Use individual groups in your regex:

```
clickedId.match(/([\d]+),([\d]+),([\w]+),([\w]+)/g);
```

Then the rest should work

Instead your put everything into a single group making the whole expression matched as a single string

Comment: `match` doesn't work that way in Javascript. The result for what you suggested would be `["3,1,Mayer,Jack"]`.

Comment: Just to clear that out, `/([\d]+),([\d]+),([\w]+),([\w]+)/g.exec('(3,1,Mayer,Jack)')` would return `["3,1,Mayer,Jack", "3", "1", "Mayer", "Jack"]`.